# Web Service freezes after startup with Application_Start() method in Global.asax

Tags: c#, forms, web-services, global-asax

I am using a Web Service method returning a list that's executing for about 40 seconds after my Web Service startup (the method is launched from `Application_Start()` event in `Global.asax`).

The problem is that the Web Service is freezed for the time that this method needs and my app won't start until it gets this list (actually it starts, but is also freezed and doesn't even show the Form).

Is there any way to deal with it? Maybe to call this method in `Application_Start()` asynchronously? Any help would be very appreciated.

Code in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebService WS = new WebService();
        WS.RecursiveFileProcessor();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could launch that mechanism as a seperate task:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
    {
        WebService WS = new WebService();
        WS.RecursiveFileProcessor();
    });
}
```

This should stop from your service hanging.